# How to count how many blank columns after the last not bank?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a way to get the number of empty columns until the last one (December), counting from the last non-empty cell in the same row.

Something like the image below:

[image]

Any ideia of what formula I could use in the cells B9:B12 to get it?
This is something relatively easy to solve using macros, but I can't use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your provided sample data, use this formula in cell B9 and copy down:

```
=13-LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:M2<>""),COLUMN(B2:M2))
```

`13` is used because column M is column 13.

EDIT:

To have a true lookup, you'd use something like this:

```
=COLUMN(M2)-LOOKUP(2,1/(INDEX($B$2:$M$5,MATCH(A9,$A$2:$A$5,0),0)<>""),COLUMN(B2:M2))
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks!